# How to properly add framing to existing wall to hang a TV (drywall to be replaced)?

Tags: drywall, framing

I currently have an old art niche (square depression) on top of my fireplace that I plan to remove by cutting its existing drywall out, re-frame as needed and install a new drywall sheet on top. Later, it will be textured and paint to match the rest of the wall.

The end goal is to hang a TV in that same place, but I am not sure how to properly add framing for it, if even possible. The following image shows the current framing that exists behind that niche (I know cause I already cut a hole in the wall and looked inside with a camera).

[image]

The two long vertical studs go from floor to ceiling. The rest of the wood framing shown in nailed to those studs just to support the current niche drywall. I am planning on removing the 3 short vertical pieces of wood as they will have no purpose once the niche is gone. Then, add new framing between the studs and the two horizontal sills (not sure if technically they can be considered sills as they are just hanging) half an inch from the wall to support the new drywall sheet.

Would that additional framing be enough to support a TV? If the answer is "No", which I assume it is, how should I add support framing to hang a TV from?

Note 1: I cannot add new studs from floor to ceiling as there is a gas fireplace at the bottom between the existing studs. The separation between those existing studs is 40 inches.

Note 2: I am new to framing and drywall, so please correct any non-sense I might be saying here.

Comment: depends on the tv.  anchors even snap toggle anchors can hold 50lbs per anchor so you can technically hang a tv ( depends on weight ) without any framing members engaged.

Answer (score 3):

As backing for the TV use plywood directly behind the new drywall.

Cut a piece of plywood the size of the opening, or just enough to fit vertically or horizontally inside the opening.

Install lumber backing against the existing studs, recessed, so that plywood plus drywall are flush with the existing drywall. For instance for 1/2in drywall and 1/2in plywood, recess the plywood backing by 1in. You can use 2x2 lumber and drive construction screws through the 2x2 and existing drywall into existing framing.

Install plywood, install drywall. Apply finish.

Now you have a large surface to attach the TV mount to. For fastening you can use toggle bolts, or screws.

Comment: Why would you recess the plywood one inch?  The drywall is only going to be 1/2" thick.  Or are you suggesting to recess the *rear* of the plywood by one inch?  (To me, zero recess is the plywood face flush with the adjacent drywall.)

Comment: @Huesmann  "recess the plywood *backing* by 1in"

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t understand the installation of the lumber backing on the studs with construction screws through existing drywall. Can you elaborate further? (Again, sorry I’m new to framing and drywall)

Comment: You mean on the “inner sides” of the existing studs, not “behind” them? Also, I was planning on removing the niche drywall all together because it has rounded edges which I want to get rid off so mudding is easier.

Comment: @toto remove the rounded corners and inner drywall and you'll have exposed studes. screw the backing 2x2 (or 2x3) sideways into those studs (so the backing is inside the niche butted vertically against the stud), one backing on left, one on right, so that you can screw the plywood, as a hole cover, against that backing. But the plywood only has to cover where the bracket will go since you will apply drywall panels over the whole opening anyway. Yes?